# Read HTML File in bytes on non HTML5 browsers

Tags: javascript, html, byte, filereader

Hello im searching for a way to upload a file from html input file and convert this file into bytes in client side and then send it to server side ASP.Net to be saved in database as a binary data.
I found a way to use HTML5 filereader APIs. 
It worked perfectly on Mozila and Google Chrome
but I want to run it on Internet explorer 10 and older versions which does not support file reader APIs.
I somehow managed to read in bytes in IE 10 but in the older versions im searching...

Comment: Sounds like you are doing it wrong, or very difficult way, and you do not state why. Why not just to use the standard `<input type=file>`?

Comment: im using HTML <input type=file> and accessing its file in client side but I have to convert this file into bytes and receive on the server to be saved in db as bianry.
I have used HTML5 filereader API. but I have to make it supportable  to all browsers i.e non HTML5 ones....

Comment: How about converting the file on the server-side? That is the right way to do it.